# How to revoke refresh token in aspnet core which is store in Identiy Server Database

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, refresh-token

Revoking a token in easy by calling the Identity server 4's RevokeAccessTokenAsync(param: accesstoken) method from Aspnet core (API Layer).
I can easily get the access token for the logged-in user as I can get it from       HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("accesstoken"). However, this method doesn't work for refresh token and thus I don't have any way to disable user to get access token again.
The Refresh token is stored in the Identity server database which I don't want to access as I want to call the revoke access token from the API layer.

this get me the access token:
             access token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

this returns an empty string:
             refreshtoken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");

Comment: Hi Ayan, Welcome to the community! Please post what you have tried and more details specific to your scenario. As this question is written it is still a bit too broad to expect good answers. Please add what you have tried already, and reasons why you can't or don't want to access the Identity DB, which may be your best option for revoking user access.

Answer (score 1):

Tried something which solves my problem. Override the RevokeRefreshTokenAsync and assume the token passed is the access token, now revoke all the refresh token using the access token.

```
         public class CustomTokenRevocationResponseGenerator : TokenRevocationResponseGenerator, ITokenRevocationResponseGenerator
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Revoke refresh token only if it belongs to client doing the request
    /// </summary>
    protected override async Task<bool> RevokeRefreshTokenAsync(TokenRevocationRequestValidationResult validationResult)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Revoking refresh token");
        //assume the token is access token instead of refresh token
        var token = await ReferenceTokenStore.GetReferenceTokenAsync(validationResult.Token);
        if (token != null)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation($"Revoking refresh token for clientId {token.ClientId} ");
            if (token.ClientId == validationResult.Client.ClientId)
            {
                Logger.LogDebug("Refresh token revoked");
                await RefreshTokenStore.RemoveRefreshTokensAsync(token.SubjectId, token.ClientId);
                await ReferenceTokenStore.RemoveReferenceTokensAsync(token.SubjectId, token.ClientId);
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.LogWarning("Client {clientId} tried to revoke a refresh token belonging to a different client: {clientId}", validationResult.Client.ClientId, token.ClientId);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }



    public CustomTokenRevocationResponseGenerator(IReferenceTokenStore referenceTokenStore, IRefreshTokenStore refreshTokenStore, ILogger<TokenRevocationResponseGenerator> logger) : base(referenceTokenStore, refreshTokenStore, logger)
    {
    }
}
```